# Puppeteer Scrap How get the image tag from it source

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I want to scrap a website ,when I click on image popup modal opened that I want to scrap, the image  don't have classname,all images as shown below have same attributes just src?
Note I want the get tag image of src = "assets/images/2.svg " and click on it
[image]

when I do this :

```
 import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
  async function scrap() {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
   });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://www.labforme.com/Login/");
  await page.waitForNavigation({
   waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
  });
 await page.waitForSelector("img")
 const imgs =await page.evaluate(()=>{
   Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img'))
 })
 console.log(imgs)
 console.log(typeof(imgs))
 await browser.close();
  }
scrap()
```

I get both console.log : undefined
How can I grap the image tag to click on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after long time I solved it:

```
 await page.$$eval("img", (images) => {
     const imgSource = "2.svg";
     for (const image of images) {
      const src = image.src;
       if (src.includes(imgSource)) {
        image.click();
       }
      }
    });
```